# How do you name a class/package/module like

Tags: perl, naming-conventions, moose

How would you name a package who's sole purpose was to extend another module so you could apply roles to it? I need a package that extends (sub classes) [Template::Context](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Context.pm) with [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose.pm) So I can then create roles and traits to apply to it, but I don't know what to name this package (class). Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since its Moose-specific role-ification, I'd have Moose in the name.  Template::Context::Moosified.  Or Template::Context::WithAntlers.

But having an intermediate subclass just so you can stick roles onto it is weird.  You can skip that middleman and simply declare composed classes directly.

```
package Template::Context::ForBreakfast;

use Moose;
extends "Template::Context";
with "Bacon", "Eggs", "Toast";
```

The class name should fall out of the role composition.

Comment: I don't really plan on using them as /roles/ (e.g. using 'with') I plan on using them as traits and having them composed onto the class much more dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is approved but you can always *try* applying the Role directly.

```
package R; 
use Moose::Role; 
sub f { say 42 } 

package main; 
use URI;
R->meta->apply( Moose::Meta::Class->initialize( 'URI' ) ); 
URI->new->f
```

Granted this needs some sugaring up, has absolutely no guarantees to work long term, and is probably totally unsupported. This is however how the MOP unsugared effectively works.